# AngularJS : How can I compile a directive as another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have Angular directives that compile

1. `<greeting />` to `<print-greeting />` and
2. `<print-greeting />` to `Hello World!`

How can I put the `greeting` tag in my HTML and have it compile to `print-greeting` and then finally display `Hello World!`?  It currently stops after turning it into `print-greeting`.

**Here is my code: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZFNUYPCuk2JCDZ7zmCr?p=preview).**

---

*Directives copied from the above plunker:*

`greeting` directive

```
// Transforms <greeting /> into <print-greeting />
app.directive("greeting", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
      priority: 2,
      compile: function ($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {

      var template = '<print-greeting />';
      $templateElement.replaceWith(template);

      return function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) { };
    }
  };
});
```

`print-greeting` directive

```
// Transforms <print-greeting /> into "Hello World!"
app.directive("printGreeting", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    priority: 1,
    compile: function ($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {
      var template = 'Hello World!';
       $templateElement.replaceWith(template);

       return function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) { };
     }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a change to the already compiled template. In order to cause the secondary directive to get compiled, you need to recompile:

```
return function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $compile($element);
};
```

[Fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BIYZ6EmAXmG8i195gCaM?p=preview)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I tried something similar, but I didn't know you needed to call $compile at link time (and using the scope).

Comment: Great - I'm glad! Note that I updated the explanation and demo. I realized that while my change worked, the reasoning was wrong the first time around.